# meanig of a sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning, verbs, subjects

Meaning of "Many of those despicable wretches does my present acquaintance with infamy and wickedness enable me to number among the heroes of debauchery."(Johnson's *Rambler* No. 170) I cannot find out the subject and the main verb of this sentence, so I cannot understand the meaning of this sentence at all. Could anyone help me grasp this sentence, by paraphrasing into easy English? The following is the context of this sentence.
Many of those despicable wretches does my present acquaintance with infamy and wickedness enable me to number among the heroes of debauchery. Reptiles whom their own servants would have despised, had they not been their servants, and with whom beggary would have disdained intercourse, had she not been allured by hopes of relief.

Answer (score 1):

(My present acquaintance with infamy and wickedness) enable[s] me to number (many of those despicable wretches) among the heroes of debauchery.

I've looked it up, and the speaker is apparently a girl who has been sexually abused by her foster father. 'Those despicable wretches' are presumably men who behave like that, and 'heroes' is of course meant ironically.